# global post variable not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I understand that the Wordpress global `$post` may not work until a certain point because it hasnt been loaded, but Im wondering is there a workaround for this.

Basically Im building a plugin specifically for a client. At the moment the variable is showing nothing.

This code is in a plugin in the plugins folder.

Im looking to make sure it only loads javascript (Ive left out that bit) when on specific pages (selected by the user), at the moment its loading on all pages.

My other option is to do it all on a php template, but to be honest I wanted to write it as a plugin with a view to customizing it for more generic use in the future, plus I have little experience with plugins so Im trying to improve that side of things also.

```
function include_js() {
  global $post;
  print_r($post);

  if(is_object($post) && $post->ID == 14 ){ 
   // do stuff
   wp_enqueue_script('include-map',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'map.js');
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'include_js' );
```

EDIT: I realised my main issue is that I want to include the javascript and because of that I need `wp_enqueue_script` , but I can only seem to get that work if you use the `init` action, which happens before the loop.

Comment: The `$post` global is available only whilst inside the loop. Are you accessing the variable's value whilst inside the loop?

Comment: no im guessing not, I probably should have put my question a little differently, the issue is that I want to include javascript properly using the wordpress way, but I can only use `wp_enqueue_script` when added into `init` right?

Comment: Actually you should hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` like this `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js' );` - No need for the `init` hook at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your edit, try hooking to `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `init`. Like this:

```
function include_js() {
    global $post;
    print_r( $post );

    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->ID == 14 ) { 
        // do stuff
        wp_enqueue_script( 'include-map',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'map.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js' );
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Thank you , I think its about time I dug deeper to learn about actions and when to use them

Answer (score 0):

You should test $wp_query->queried_object_id instead of $post->id:

```
function include_js() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->queried_object_id == 14 ) { 
        // do stuff
        //...
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any globals etc. You can simply use [`is_single($post)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) to check if you are on a specific single post and then enqueue your script. You should always always use the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook to hook your function to to enqueue scripts and styles

```
function include_js() {
  if(is_single(14)) { 
   // do stuff
   wp_enqueue_script('include-map',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'map.js');
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_js', 999 );
```

Remeber also, always add priority when adding custom scripts/styles. See [`add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)